# How to give TemporalFusionTransformer model a name?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, time-series, pytorch-forecasting

Im working on creating `.py` scripts that preprocess some data and then train a `TemporalFusionTransformer` model. After the training, I have a function that logs the evaluation metrics in a `.txt` file, whose name should be `model_name@datetime.txt`. Everywhere that I have looked, searched, in the [docs](https://pytorch-forecasting.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pytorch_forecasting.models.temporal_fusion_transformer.TemporalFusionTransformer.html#pytorch_forecasting.models.temporal_fusion_transformer.TemporalFusionTransformer), on forums, articles, I cannot find a way to give my models a custom name? Any idea how to do this?

**Edit**: Can someone with >1500 reputation please add the tag `temporalfusiontransformer` in he tags section. Users below 1500 reputation (like me) cannot add new tags to the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a custom class inheriting the original that requires and stores a name property on top of what other functionality the model provides, e.g.

```py
class NamedTFT(TemporalFusionTransformer):
    def __init__(self, name: str, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NamedTFT, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.name = name
```

then you could grab the model's name afterwards.

Comment: yes, that is a good solution, but I was wondering is there a build in method, or attribute that can set a name for the model?

Comment: I couldn't know. if the documentation doesn't say so, i don't see why there would. You could also just write it forcibly on an initialized model, i.e. `model.name = "name"`, but that's hacky.